# What is an efficient way to create/manage RESTful API with grails?

Tags: api, rest, grails, restful-authentication

I've built my first grails application. My URL mappings are what the default application provides:

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

**Senario**

I have a controller called `ColorController` with actions `save` and `list`. It simply does something like this:

```
def save () {
   def colorInstance = new Color(params)
   colorInstance.save(flush: true)
}

def list () {
   [colorList: Color.list, colorTotal: Color.count()]
}
```

I would like to build a simple API for these actions.

- The save action should accept parameters as JSON and provide a successful message if the records save.
- The list action should provide the list as JSON

**Questions**

- Should I make a separate URL mapping for api? (e.g. `http://<domain>/<app>/rest/controller/action`)
- Should I be making a separate controller for my API's
- I am using spring security plugin for authentication. But at some point I might want to authenticate the restful api as well. What are some solutions for that?
- If I use the same controller, how can I modify these simple actions to do what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before even looking below for my opinion/answers I would suggest to visit this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932670/implement-a-rest-api-in-a-grails-app) for the basic understanding of RESTful WS in Grails.

**Opinions:**

- *"The save action should accept parameters as JSON and provide a successful message if the records save"* - Save is mapped to POST RESTful. Instead of binding a JSON body to `params` it is bound to the `request`. In order to access the JSON object you just need to use `request.JSON` in the action method.

  `request.JSON instanceof JSONObject`
- *"The list action should provide the list as JSON"* - `list()` action is mapped to a GET Request and you can render the map as JSON in the `list()` as below

//Controller list()

```
import grails.converter.JSON
def list () {
   [colorList: Color.list, colorTotal: Color.count()] as JSON
}
```

**Answers to Questions:-**

1. *Should I make a separate URL mapping for api?*
   Abiding by the basics of REST, the client should only access the resource (`Color` in this case) and should not bother about the underlying `controller` or `action`. The server side logic should be abstracted from the client. URL Mapping is what the client would use to as form of request. I would have something like this in my url mapping for `Color` Resource.

`/color/$id?(resource: "color")`

or

```
/color/$id?(controller: 'color'){
    action = [GET: "list", POST: "save"]
}
```

- *Should I be making a separate controller for my API's?* - Depends on the way the App is designed. You also can have the above controller as the API. For example, currently I am working on a grails app which used `AngularJS` in the front End which connects to the Grails APP RESTFully. In order to achieve I had a `RestClientController` which works as an API to Angular. The rationale behind having a REST api in the same app is that in future we can expose the underlying service to external clients other than the `Angular` client present in the app itself.
- *I am using spring security plugin for authentication. But at some point I might want to authenticate the restful api as well. What are some solutions for that?* - You can use Spring Security here as well. In my case I am using the plugin and I secure the `controller` by using the plugin's annotated component `@Secured`. I have custom `OAuth` enabled as well for authorization which interacts to the company wide LDAP and AD Groups.
- *If I use the same controller, how can I modify these simple actions to do what I need.* - I think you would have got the answer to this question by now (after going through the SO question I mentioned above). Here is my opinion, `controller` `actions` can route to appropriate `service` classes which does the business implementations based on the request parameters.

For example,

```
//Action
def show(){
   if(params.id){
      colorService.getColor()
   } else {
      colorService.searchColor()
   }
}
```

In the above example, the url mapping would be `/color/123` or `/color`. In the former case, it will get the `color` and in the later it will search the colors

Comment: That helps a lot!! thanks for your valuable input. As a side note, have you come across any sample projects on github that expose restful api in grails app?

Comment: You will find number of such projects in github. I searched one for you right now. You can refer [this](https://github.com/padcom/grails-json-rest-api) if you want. Have a look at `JsonRestApiUrlMappings`.