# How to generating API key and maintain multiple versions of REST API with grails

Tags: rest, grails

I am making a simple REST API with grails. The url for my REST API will look similar to:

`http://<domain>/<appname>/rest/0.1/$apiKey/$controller/$action/$id`

**Questions**

- I came across this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10419894/44286) which mentions that using `withFormat` an API version can be maintained. How can I do this?
- What is a central way to validate that the `$apiKey` is valid? Should I be doing this in a filter?

Comment: withFormat helps in making the REST service handle variety of client request. Client A would need a JSON response from the service, client B is only interested for an XML response, withFormat helps in entertaining both the clients. API versioning is not done using withFormat.

Comment: You don't really want to be writing your own security filters - Shiro and Spring Security both have implementations that will help you do this sort of authentication ( albeit not necessarily easily or in grails plugins ).

Comment: +1 @tomas. Here see [this to version RESTful service](http://barelyenough.org/blog/2008/05/versioning-rest-web-services/). If you do not follow a `schema`, you have to try the "Alternate approaches".