# CRUD operation Grails

Tags: rest, grails, jax-rs

I need to read data from existing database is it possible using
`compile "org.grails.plugins:db-reverse-engineer:4.0.0"`?

My operations are: user should read data from existing table, create new record, create new coulmn, edit coulmn name, edit records.
View format will be in grid like xml grid.

Which technology is the best for these operations in grails, I have plan to work on javascript using `jaxrs`, is it good to do?

Answer (score 0):

DB Reverse Engineering Plugin (`org.grails.plugins:db-reverse-engineer:4.0.0`) allows you to generate domain classes using existing DB. After you generate them - just use GORM to perform CRUD operations. You can read about GORM [here](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/GORM.html)

You can implement REST api in Grails using standart ways, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932670/implement-a-rest-api-in-a-grails-app) to get high level understanding. If you need jaxrs-  there is a [plugin](https://github.com/budjb/grails-jaxrs) for that.